# Почему callback функцию нельзя сравнить с null?

Tags: javascript, функции, callback

```
        let loop = function(times = 0, callback = null) {
        for (let i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
            // if (callback == null) {
            //     clear();
            // }
            callback(i);
            console.log(i);
        }
    }

    function show(par) {
        console.log('massage ' + par);
    }

    function clear(par) {
        // console.log('...' + par);
    }

    loop(3, show);
    // loop(3);
```

Почему нельзя сравнивать callback с null? Отладчик ругается:

> Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

когда не передаю второй аргумент (то есть callback == null).

Comment: Я просто хотел чтобы при вызове loop(3) без второго параметра программа не выводила сообщение т.е не запускала бы show().

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы пытаетесь вызвать  `callback(i);` в той ситуации, когда у вас `callback = null`. Вот он и пишет что это не функция.

Я не знаю что вы хотите получить, но в таких ситуациях обычно делается проверка на null перед вызовом. И вызов делается только на не null функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Сравнить можно. Только вызывать/не вызывать ее надо в зависимости от результата сравнения.

```
if (callback == null) {
  ...
} else { // !!!
  callback(i);
}
```

или

```
if (callback != null) {
  callback(i);
}
```

или

```
let loop = function(times = 0, callback = null) {
   if (callback == null)
       return;
   for (let i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при вызове loop(3) без второго параметра программа не выводила сообщение т.е не запускала бы show().

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема не в проверке на null, а в том, что если `callback` равен null, то цикл не заканчивается и продолжает отрабатывать дальше, то есть пытаются выполниться  строки

```
callback(i);
console.log(i);
```

что конечно же невозможно. Вот и ругается, что `callback` не является функцией.

В итоге, нужно, если `callback == null` либо делать `break;`, либо `continue;`, в зависимости от логики

либо `if {} else {}`